# How do I get the next 12PM PST in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for the epoch time of the next 12PM in PST. The product I am working on expires every 12PM PST.

How do I get the next 12PM PST in JavaScript?

Comment: it seems like if you have: TODAY 12pm and TOMORROW 12pm, it should be pretty easy to determine which one is the closest one in the future from NOW.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty JavaScript function that gets the current time, checks if noon has passed and adds a day if it has, then creates a new noon based on that result.

```
    function getNextNoon() {
        let now = new Date();
        if (now.getHours()>12) {
            now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
        }
        let nextNoon = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 12);
        return nextNoon.valueOf();
    }
```